# Writing elegant JavaScript instead of if-then branches

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coding-style

How can I make the following code more elegant and readable?

```
if (this.flag === 1) {
  this.value -= 0.1;
}
if (this.value <= 0) {
  this.flag = 0;
}

if (this.flag === 0) {
  this.value += 0.1;
}
if (this.value >= 1) {
  this.flag = 1;
}
```

Edit: Let's say, for simplicity's sake, I'm changing the opacity of an object, and I want it to fade in and out from 0 to 1 over and over inside some sort of loop. `.value` is the opacity, and `.flag` is to tell it when to switch directions.

Comment: Putting it in a logical sequence would be a good first step. ;-) Consider a [*switch statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: It's impossible to say if you could refactor or not without more context. Is this.flag a binary choice, if so why is it not a boolean and/or part of an if/else conditional? etc.

As for readability, you're using proper indentation so there's that at least.

Comment: @RobG - It looks like a progression.

Comment: What should happen if `this.value` neither 0 nor 1?

Comment: @TravisJ—wonder what happens when `0 < this.flag < 1`.

Comment: There is simply not enough here. Please edit your question with haste to avoid having wasted everyone's time.

Comment: @TravisJ Updated with an example where this might apply.

Comment: @RobG Aren't switch statements notoriously slow? Or did I make that up?

Comment: @daveycroqet—given the incredibly turgid code I see on web sites, even if a 4 case switch statement runs like molasses in the arctic, it's effect on overall performance will be something less than infinitesimal. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* simplify some `if-else` scenarios with shorthand notations like below.

```
this.flag = this.value <= 0 ? 0 : 1;
this.value = this.value + (this.flag === 1 ? -0.1 : 0.1);
```

However, your script, in its current form, uses exclusive `if` conditions that don't cover all possible values of `flag` and `value` with an `else` block. Depending on whether you care about that, my proposal above could break your code.

---

**EDIT** - based on OP updates

`flag` should be a boolean `true/false`.

```
this.flag = this.value > 0;
this.value += (this.flag ? -0.1 : 0.1);
```

---

**EDIT 2** - based on comments

Why should `this.flag` be manipulated through the value of `this.value`? The flag should be controlled through other means such as a checkbox or something, so your opacity change script should really be just this:

```
this.value += (this.flag ? -0.1 : 0.1);
```

If you're trying to auto-toggle the flag when the opacity reaches `0` or `1`, you can do this:

```
this.value += (this.flag ? -0.1 : 0.1);

if(this.value === 1 || this.value === 0) {
  this.flag = !this.flag;
}
```

Please note that this answer has already drifted outside of the scope of the question, which was to have a more elegant approach to conditionals. You'd be better off asking a new SO question if you need to discuss any further.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. This is the kind of thing I was looking for with ternaries. However, your edited suggestion makes the opacity flow in only one direction: down.

Comment: I just followed the flow of your code. I think that the value of `flag` shouldn't be changed by the value of `value`, and be controlled on its own, so I'd leave it at `this.value += (this.flag ? -0.1 : 0.1);` and have some other means of toggling the `flag` value.

Comment: Phenomenal answers all around. Every edit was more insightful than the last. Sincerely, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have right now I would do this :

```
    if (this.flag === 1) {
      this.value -= 0.1;
    } else if (this.flag === 0) {
      this.value += 0.1;
    }

    if (this.value <= 0) {
      this.flag = 0;
    } else if (this.value >= 1) {
      this.flag = 1;
    }
```

But can flag be a boolean value?  If so you don't need to the the numerical value check.  Also can this.value be anywhere between 0-1?  Flag isn't set in this case.  If possible I would refactor the code like this but it depends on the logic you are trying to implement

```
    if (this.flag) {
      this.value -= 0.1;
    } else {
      this.value += 0.1;
    }
    if (this.value <= 0) {
      this.flag = 0;
    } else {
      this.flag = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This seems only marginally better than I had, just more tightly nested with else statements.

Answer (score 1):

This changes the outcome a bit, but I think it is what you actually want:

```
if (this.flag === 1) {
  this.value -= 0.1;
  if (this.value <= 0)
    this.flag = 0;
} else /* if (this.flag === 0) */ {
  this.value += 0.1;
  if (this.value >= 1)
    this.flag = 1;
}
```

While it still might not be elegant, it's at least easy to understand, as you only have a cyclomatic complexity of 4 (instead of 16 as in your original code).

---

For an elegant solution, you'd change even more. Instead of using a "flag" for the direction, you could represent the direction itself by the amount of change:

```
 this.value += this.dir;
 if (this.value >= 1)
     this.dir = -0.1;
 else if (this.value <= 0)
     this.dir = 0.1;
```

Or then again, maybe even

```
 this.value += this.dir;
 if (this.value <= 0 || this.value >= 1)
     this.dir *= -1;
```